# Laravel: join Eloquent models

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

**Question**. How can I use Eloquent to produce this query:

SELECT campaigns.name, users.name FROM campaigns LEFT JOIN users on campaigns.gamemaster_id = users.id where campaigns.status = 1

**Campaigns**

```
id  gamemaster_id name        status
1   1             campaign1   1
2   2             campaign2   1
```

**Users**

```
id name
1  rick
2  bob
```

**Result**

```
id gamemaster_id name      status gamemaster_name
1  1             campaign1 1      rick
2  2             campaign2 1      bob
```

**Campaign model**

```
class Campaign extends Model
{
    public function gamemaster()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'gamemaster_id');
    }
}
```

My try to make Eloquent, but that fails:

```
$result = Campaign::where('status', '=', 1)->with('gamemaster')->select('name')->orderBy('users.updated_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in two ways, first using the query builder,

```
$campaigns = DB::table('campaigns')->leftJoin('users', 'campaigns.gamemaster_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select(['campaigns.name as name', 'users.name as gamemaster_name'])
            ->where('campaigns.status', '=', 1)
            ->orderBy('users.updated_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

And with eager loading, you can get the campaigns like below. However, to sort by relation property, you need an another layer which is not that easy to implement.

```
$campaigns = Campaign::where('status', '=', 1)->with(['gamemaster' => function($query){
    $query->select(['id', 'name']);
}]->select('id', 'gamemaster_id', 'name')->get();
```

But you can use collection functions to easily sort it (However, it will take more execution time)

```
$campaigns = Campaign::where('status', '=', 1)->with(['gamemaster' => function($query){
    $query->select(['id', 'gamemaster_id', 'name', 'updated_at']);
}]->select('id', 'name')->get()->sortByDesc(function ($campaign) {
    return $campaign->gamemaster->updated_at;
})
```

Comment: Thanks. The first one seem to work. But the eager loading give this query: "select `id`, `name` from `campaigns` where `status` = ?" Perhaps it is missing a join part?

Comment: Welcome, no need for a join there, it selects gamemasters where they belong to the campaigns that have the status 1. So two queries are being run there, first it selects campaigns, secondly, it selects users that belong to that campaigns. Has it returned any errors or showed unexpected results? I should also note that, to order campaigns with users' updated at attribute, you need an another layer that is why the join approach is easier.

Comment: When I run it, it says this: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'gamemaster_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id`, `gamemaster_id`, `name`, `updated_at` from `sh_users` where `sh_users`.`id` in (0))  . I prefixed my table with sh, in my actual project.

Comment: My bad, user table does not have `gamemaster_id` field, it's the campaigns. Updated.

Comment: As an extra note. Using DB::table will ensure you lose all functions in the class you want! The second and third solution solves that by ensuring you have a list returned of that class (Campaign) with the functions in it.

Answer (score 5):

The following query should work:

```
Campaign::whereStatus(1)
    ->join('users', 'campaigns.gamemaster_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select('campaigns.name', 'users.name')
    ->orderBy('users.updated_at', 'desc')
    ->get()
```

Comment: Do you mean: Campaign::where('status, '=', 1)
    ->join('users', 'campaigns.gamemaster_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select('campaigns.name', 'users.name')
    ->get() . When I run it nothing gets returned. Hm, is it possible to see the SQL that just run?

Comment: whereStatus(1) or where('status', '=', 1) is the same. You missed a ' after your status. If you just do "Campaign::whereStatus(1)->get()", what do you have ?

Comment: I see that your query returns the 2 user names, but only that. And the query seem to be: "select `campaigns`.`name`, `users`.`name` from `campaigns` inner join `users` on `campaigns`.`gamemaster_id` = `users`.`id` where `campaigns`.`status` = ?" But it do not have order by.

Comment: You can use toSql() instead of get() to show the query.

Comment: Of course, because you didn't ask for orderby in your question but you can add ->orderBy('users.update_at', 'desc') to get it work.